# $F=2+3x+5x^2+7x^3+ \dots$ $G=1-2x+4x^2-8x^3+ \dots$ What will be $F/G$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

$F=2+3x+5x^2+7x^3+ \dots \\
G=1-2x+4x^2-8x^3+ \dots$

I didn't get the correct result, how can I compute it?

Comment: Are the coefficients of $F$ prime numbers?

Comment: Yes, they are prime numbers

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee hows it related

Comment: @ArchisWelankar, $$G$$ can be found to be $$(1+2x)^{-1}$$

Comment: Yes but what about F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$G$ is a geometric series, so when $|x|<\frac12$ it converges to $\frac{1}{1+2x}$. Hence

$$\frac FG = \left(1+2x\right)F=\sum_{n\ge 0} (p_n + 2p_{n-1})x^n = 2 + 7x+11x^2+17x^3+...$$

Answer (score 3):

Algebraically,
$$G = 1 - 2x + 4x^2 - 8x^3 + \cdots = {1\over 1+2x},$$
so $1/G=1+2x$, and
$$F/G = (2+3x+5x^2+7x^3+\cdots)(1+2x).$$
Now multiply it out:
$$\eqalign{F/G &= 2 + (3+2\cdot2)x + (5+2\cdot3)x^2+(7+2\cdot5)x^3+\cdots\cr
&= 2+7x+11x^2+17x^3+\cdots\cr}$$